# autoLink phone only work for saved number

Tags: android

I am implementing phone call demo, in my demo i generated link to textview using autoLink = phone, but its only work when i have this number saved on my contact-list, i cant able to generate link on random number..

i also tried clickable= true. and also apply Linkify class, but this not work either.
and also applied autoLink="all" it's also not working, i dont know what is wrong. i also set permission in manifest.

here is my code:

```
            txtfromnumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtfromnumber);
            int mask = Linkify.ALL;
            Linkify.addLinks(txtfromnumber, mask);
            txtfromname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtfromname);
            txtreceivernumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtreceivernumber);
            int mask2 = Linkify.ALL;

    txtreceivernumber.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,
                        Uri.parse("Tel:"+txtreceivernumber.getText().toString().trim()));
                if (dialIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    dialIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        dialIntent.setPackage("com.android.phone");
                    }else {
                        dialIntent.setPackage("com.android.server.telecom");
                    }
                    startActivity(dialIntent);
                }
            }
        });

        txtfromnumber.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                        Uri.parse("+"+txtfromnumber.getText().toString().trim()));
                if (dialIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    dialIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        dialIntent.setPackage("com.android.phone");
                    }else {
                        dialIntent.setPackage("com.android.server.telecom");
                    }
                    startActivity(dialIntent);
                }
            }
        });
```

and here is my xml file code:

```
               <TextView
                android:clickable="true"
                android:autoLink="all"
                android:id="@+id/txtreceivernumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

              <TextView
                android:clickable="true"
                android:autoLink="all"
                android:id="@+id/txtreceivernumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="17sp" />
```

here my reciver number txtview working fine bcz this number is saved on my contact list, but FromNumber txtview is not setting any link or anythinig. bcz its random number.

> Question 2.

how to call direct instead of opening dialer window.?  any help would be appriciated.. many thanks in advance.

> Note. this question is solved. and this is the working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just type any number and think it will be detect as phone number whether it is in your contact or not.

***One example***

If I add 1234567890 in my contact and add text in my textview with autolink enable it will not detect it as phone number because android is not consider it as a phone number even if you store it in your contact.

***Another example***

I pass 9854856589 in my text and then it will detect it as a phone number even if it is not in my contact.

So if possible please add proper phone number or nearest to number so android detect it as valid phone number and it is not necessarily in your contact .

**Question 2 :**

```
 String uri = "tel:" + yourNumber ;
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
 startActivity(intent);
```

*add Permission*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: but i am adding proper number, bcz number is comming from outgoing call.

Comment: but problem is number is 12 digit code.. bcz every outgoing call is bydefault put 91 ahead of original number

Comment: here is the number.. 9188662xxxxx

Comment: try to add 10 digit number . or add +91

Comment: just add + it will work . because you add country code

Comment: or remove country code and just pass 10 digit string

Comment: i cant bcz its comming from the webservice to the txtview. is there any way to remove 91 from the textview..

Comment: you have to create one method in a way that it will check country code from phone number. and create valid phone number . I will give some hint like you can add + or 00  , check first three digit for country code. happy coding.

Comment: thank you so much for help.. it work now.. i change my php side coding add + before number nd it working fine.

Comment: welcome @SagarChavada you can accept my answer if it is helpful.

Comment: hey do you have any idea about my second question?

Comment: what? i m already using Action_CAll but its also opening dialer box.. is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SpannableString and ClickableSpan!

```
    String tel = textview.getText().toString();
    SpannableString sSpan = new SpannableString(tel);
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
           //intent dial or call
        }
        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    };
```